# Add text in custom categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

can you please advise me how can I add text to the product category under products?

Thank you

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you´re using wordpress plugin try it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_my_text');
function add_my_text() {
    echo '<p>More Content on the Way.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I use wordpress. I have a total of three product categories and I would like to have different text under each product categories.